# Filter and plot dataframe values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

[image: dataframe screenshot]

and I wanted to create a loop that filters when for example period = 1 and plots a graph with all the values of x and y in which period = 1. How could I do this?

Comment: Please create a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

We can `subset` the data where 'Time' is 1, and `plot` the 'x' and 'y' column

```
with(subset(df1, Time ==1), plot(XPoblacion_Update3, YPoblacion_Update3))
```